# Truncate in SQL Server rounding values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I'm looking for a way to truncate or drop extra decimal places in SQL. I've found a way but i'm having a problem with values that do not have 3 decimal places.

I have the following data

```
ProductID   |  Price   |  Amount  
------------+----------+---------
   100      |  50.01   |   1
   101      |  25      |   0.789
```

It's very simple, all I need to do is get the total from each product (Price * Amount).

My query:

```
select 
    [ProductID],
    [Price],
    [Amount],
    round(SUM(([Price] * [Amount])),2,1) as 'Total'
from 
    [Tables]
```

What I get is:

```
ProductID  |   Price   |  Amount   |   Total
-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------
   100     |   50.01   |     1     |     50     <=======
   101     |     25    |   0.789   |    19.72
```

So, if my calculator is working, the result of this simple operation is:

```
(50.01 * 1) = 50.01
-
(25 * 0.789) = 19.725
-
```

**Question**: SQL does the trick dropping the 5 from the 19.725, but why does (50.01 * 1) equals 50?

I do know that if I use *Round((value)**,2,0**)* I'll get 50.01, but if I do that 19.725 becomes 19.73 and that is not correct for my application.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What are the data types for each of the table columns?

Comment: The type is float for both columns

Comment: never use float for financials, use decimal.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will remember that next time, for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cast price and amount to either numeric or decimal data type as shown below, you should arrive at the expected result:

```
DECLARE @Tables table 
(
    ProductID int,
    Price float,
    Amount float
);

INSERT @Tables
  (ProductID, Price, Amount)
VALUES
  (100, 50.01, 1),
  (101, 25, 0.789);

SELECT ProductID
      ,Price
      ,Amount
      ,ROUND(SUM((CAST(Price AS decimal(5,2)) * CAST(Amount AS decimal(5,3)))),2,1) AS 'Total'
FROM @Tables
GROUP BY ProductID, Price, Amount;

(2 row(s) affected)
ProductID   Price                  Amount                 Total
----------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------------------------
100         50.01                  1                      50.01000
101         25                     0.789                  19.72000

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ProductID,
       Price,
       Amount,
       CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(Price * Amount AS decimal(18,3)) AS VARCHAR),0, LEN(CAST(CAST(Price * Amount AS decimal(18,3)) AS VARCHAR))) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Total
FROM  [Tables]
```